# Cannot create directory on sdcard :S

Tags: android, directory

I have this code

```
File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" +  "new_dir");
                if (dir.mkdir()) {
                    txtView.setText(dir + " Directory created");
                } else {
                    txtView.setText(dir + " Directory is not created");
                }
```

and i also added

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

but it always goes in the else and the directory is never made :S :S

Comment: Nevermind, i got it. For some reason even though i added the permission to the manifest i still added it in the application tab in eclipse and it worked.

Comment: TRy using:  android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

Answer (score 0):

Try This code

```
 String newFolder = "/myFolder2";
 String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
 File myNewFolder = new File(extStorageDirectory + newFolder);
 (!myNewFolder.mkdir())
{
Log.e(TAG, "Create dir in sdcard failed");

              return;

}
```

User permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```